# How to tell eslint to: disable next line "'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'"

Tags: javascript, eslint

How to tell eslint to: disable next line  for

> "'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'"

*Without* [configuration](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options), **it has to be inline**.

The following doesn't seem to be working

```js
/* eslint-disable */
```

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line
```

Why:

Let's say you are writing a test inside a NON module project, and you want to prove you can or cannot dynamically import an ESM module.

```js
describe('my test', it("doesn't work", ()=> require('./my.esm.js'))
```

Where 'my.esm.js' could be

```js
export function noop {}
```

...or whatever

But the main project, nor the tests are module based.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add `"sourceType": "module"` to your eslint config file.
Here's example:

```
{
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
    }
},
"rules": {
    "semi": "error"
}
}
```

source: [eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options)

Comment: Thank you, but I need it be in-line as a comment.

Comment: @Dan okay! I understood your concern. but did it work?

Comment: ,The configuration ?  I'm pretty sure it will ... , don't see why not.  But is not what I need :(

Comment: I suggest you to refer original eslint docs for this. I have already mentioned a link in my answer. I hope you may find your answer there.

Comment: This answer does nothing for me. I still see the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Same as @kahlan88; I have `sourceType: 'module'` in .eslintrc.js and I'm still getting a error flagged when I reference `import` (e.g. `import.meta.url`)